# Request for help to undelete a question

Tags: support, vote-to-undelete

I created this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798839/android-why-is-my-activity-always-relaunched-and-why-is-my-toolbar-title-overwr

It was deleted, and for good reason.  I had failed to provide a "minimal complete verifiable example".  Sorry, I concede I was a little lazy there.

What has changed is that I've found the answer myself. And it is instructive. Rather than provide all my code I can provide the answer.  I've edited the question to include the answer, but this is the wrong place for it. Can 4 people vote to undelete it and then I'll move the answer to a proper answer?

Comment: Edit out the tag at the start of the question, please. If you feel you *must* mention it's for Android, work it into the title in a more natural way.

Comment: Has the question been improved? Because "It has a good answer" does not a good question make. For your question to be undeleted, the issues that got it deleted should be resolved in the first place.

Comment: @Patrice:  This is one of those scenarios where I'm not entirely sold that showing code is absolutely mandatory.  It'd *help*, but it's not what the question's solely missing here.

Comment: @Makoto Well given what the OP has stated the answer is, it's clearly based on information not in the question, so whether or not they provide code, the question clearly doesn't provide enough information to get an answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you want people to undelete your question then *fix the problems with it that resulted in it being deleted* (and also the problems that resulted in it being closed).   That you've found an answer to your question *while still not describing the problem sufficiently* doesn't change any of the problems with the question.  *After* you have fixed the problems in the question that resulted in it being closed and deleted (and after removing the answer from the question, because your question is where you ask your question, not where you post an answer to it) then it can be undeleted.